# R versions and associated libraries

Tags: r

When I switch R versions in RStudio will the package/library versions associated with that R version be used? My libraries are in “c:\users\user1\Documents\R\win-library” with directories for each R version on my machine. There is also a library directory in the R version location (e.g. “c:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.3\library”). The ".libPaths()" function will list both of these locations. Because there are different library directories for each version I assume they are tied together, therefore if I switch R versions the associated libraries with that version are used.

Comment: Which package library will be used depends entirely on the value of `.libPaths()`. If you see that different `.libPaths()` are set for different R versions, then that means that you can install separate packages for different R versions.

Comment: Yes. If you are running R-4.1.0 or R-4.1.2, then `c:/Users/user1/Documents/R/win-library/4.1` should be used, as well as `c:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library` (which you should never install into or change). That's the default behavior, assuming that you do not manually force `.libPaths()`, relying on the default behavior (e.g., `R_LIBS_USER` envvar) to define sane defaults. If you override it, R will try to use whatever directory you force on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above and testing on my machine R seems to use the libraries associated with whatever R version is being used in the following directories (e.g. c:/Users/user1/Documents/R/win-library/4.1; c:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/library). As @r2evans has stated above this can be changed using the .libPaths() function.